# Version control for writing ebooks

Tags: epub, calibre, publishing, editing, software

When software such as Calibre is used to generate epub, what version control is available?  To my understanding, git can be made to work with word processors by jumping through hoops.  Perhaps there are similar options for ebooks?

See also:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/22583856/262852

Comment: I don’t see the point in versioning ePub files (as archives). It would be sufficient to work with Git above the folder structure full of textual files (as a structure **for** packing up the ePub).

Comment: what about `jpeg` or other binaries?  Because git doesn't handle those well.  Everything is mostly in text/html?

Comment: Yes, therefore you could try something like [Apache Subversion](https://subversion.apache.org/).

Comment: Git handles jprg as well as subversion does (or as badly).

Answer (score 3):

Git can be used, but if you use with epub, or any other kind of archive files then you will not get a meaningful diff between versions, just store each version of the ebook. You can use Git wit literally everything, but if it is not like a simple text file, the diff will fail.

Also, you can set Git LFS for such kind of files as ebooks, it has the advantage that it will not download every version of the files when somebody clones it, just the latest version.